# How can I make 'index.html' redirect to wagtail page

Tags: django, redirect, wagtail

I'm replacing a static site with wagtail.

The static site has urls, but also exposes index.html for each page.

How can I easily remove the /index.html and have this redirect to the wagtail page ?

Answer (score 0):

You could

1. Create redirects for each /index.html URL in Wagtail's [admin UI](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/editor_manual/managing_redirects.html), or
2. Add some middleware which intercepts and redirects /index.html URLs, or
3. Add a rewrite rule in Nginx / Apache

Comment: 1. - There are over 50 pages already and it needs to be editable by nontechnical people.    2.  could be a possibility.     3.   Is something I want to avoid as it's a pain to change that bit of the infrastructure for this project.

Comment: It looks like RoutablePageMixin is what I need here, I'll have a play and post a solution if it it works.

Comment: (or accept someone else example of same, but seems a bit lazy of me).